# How do I stop focus from changing when I reset EditTexts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-edittext, android-view

My fragment has a Reset button that clears some EditTexts and puts default values in others. When this happens, focus goes to the last EditText that was given a default value (and sometimes makes the screen scroll). I would like no focus to change. Is there a way to prevent focus change while the screen is resetting?

EDIT:
As requested, here is a sample of my layout file which demonstrates how views are organized (full file was 700+ lines). All EditTexts are nested like these examples. Notice that my EditTexts are nested either 1 or 2 layers within the RelativeLayout within the ScrollView. Therefore, for their common parent, they are grandchildren or great grandchildren.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<!-- So that it will scroll if in landscape  mode -->

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_new_grade"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!-- my main layout frame -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_lay_new_grade"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp" >

            <!-- Multiple instances like this -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linlay_avg_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_grade_calc_prompt"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_grade_calc_cur_grade"
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text=""
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:maxLength="7" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- 2 instances like this -->    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linlay_weight_other_categories"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/linlay_weight_input"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_grade_calc_other_categories"
                        android:layout_width="95dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:text="100"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:maxLength="7" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- 1 radio group like this (options with EditTexts) -->
            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_grade_calc_prompt"
                android:layout_below="@id/splitline_horz6"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linlay_radio_group_0"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <!-- stuff -->

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_grade_calc_target"
                        android:layout_width="85dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:maxLength="7"
                        android:width="70dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: please post your layout file.

Comment: see the update below

Comment: can you provide the Full 700+ line xml file? I am noticing that the XML is also not well formed, you have an open attribute at RadioGroup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take all the views that currently are on screen, and get the view that currently has focus.

**Update to reflect your XML**

**Update Revised Again After taking a deeper look at the XML**
Something like:

```
// Hold a reference to the id
int childIdWithFocus = 0;

// Your main Layout which is the first item of your scroll view
ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.rel_lay_new_grade);

// Then get count of all views
int childCount = parentViewGroup.getChildCount();

// Then using the Views count
for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++){

  // Check if the child elements are ViewGroups 
  if(parentViewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup){

    ViewGroup innerParent = (ViewGroup) parentViewGroup.getChildAt(i);
    int innerParentCount = innerParent.getChildCount();

     // Loop through inner view groups
     for(int j = 0; j < innerParentCount; j++){

         // Check for nested ViewGroups
         if(innerParent.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup){

          // Again get the childCount of the ViewGroup 
          ViewGroup childInnerViewGroup = (ViewGroup) innerParent.getChildAt(i);
          int childCountOfInnerParentView = childInnerViewGroup.getChildCount();
             
            for(int k = 0; k < childCountOfInnerParentView; k++){

               // Now check for EditText since we are in another level
               if(innerParent.getChildAt(k) instanceof EditText){

                   EditText currentEditText = (EditText) innerParent.getChildAt(k);
                   boolean isFocused = currentEditText.isFocused();
                   if(isFocused){
                     childIdWithFocus = currentEditText.getId();
                     return;
                   }
               }
            }
        }
      }
   }
}


// Then sometime after refreshing your view

EditText childWithFocus = (EditText) findViewById(childIdWithFocus);
childWithFocus.requestFocus();
```

**The biggest problem with this method**

Directly from Android Docs:

> public final boolean requestFocus ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Call this to try to give focus to a specific view
> or to one of its descendants. A view will not actually take focus if
> it is not focusable (isFocusable() returns false), or if it is
> focusable and it is not focusable in touch mode
> (isFocusableInTouchMode()) while the device is in touch mode. See also
> focusSearch(int), which is what you call to say that you have focus,
> and you want your parent to look for the next one. This is equivalent
> to calling requestFocus(int, Rect) with arguments FOCUS_DOWN and null.
>
> Returns Whether this view or one of its descendants actually took
> focus.

Hope this helps. If you are using dynamic views and do not have an xml file with all the EditText's you will have to wait until after your entire view has been created before getting the child count because it would return 0 by default since this parent layout would know nothing about dynamic views.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but it's not working for me, I think because my EditTexts are not all part of the same parent. Some are nested under one parent and others under 2. And even when I call `mEditText.requestFocus()` on a known static view at the end of my reset method, focus ends up in another EditText (one that I've already reset to its "100" default).

Comment: @NSouth can you post your XML and then i can update the code. I know this will be possible if you search for the right Views. Thanks

Comment: I've added my XML. Thanks so much for helping me with this.

Comment: I have suggested an edit which works with one more level of ViewGroups. This excerpt finds the focused EditText correctly. *However*, even when I call `requestFocus` on the *correct EditText*, another EditText ends up being focused. I don't know when this happens, as I can confirm that the correct EditText has received focus at the end of my method, yet after that it obviously loses focus.

Comment: @NSouth did you have luck with this?

Comment: Honestly, not really. I can verify that `requestFocus()` returns `true` for the desired EditText and that it has focus at the end of my function, but a different EditText ends up with focus. As far as my code is concerned, nothing else happens after this function (called by an onClickListener). Still, I've appreciated the help and discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You could save which EditText, or which UI control currently has focus in the onSaveInstanceState, and then use the savedinstance object to restore the focus to that control when the screen is restoring the UI.

Which method is used for restoring the instance is different for activities than for fragments. With Activities it's onRestoreInstanceState, and with Fragments you use onActivityCreated.

Remember to make sure that in the onActivityCreated method in your fragment, that you check that the passed instanceState Bundle is not null first before accessing it, since the instanceState is only created when creating Fragment the initial time, or when re-creating the Fragment.